# SvelteKit form actions and redirect

Tags: sveltekit

In my SvelteKit app I have a form that uses a form action:

```
<form action="/login?/logout" method="POST">
    <button type="submit">Logout</button>
</form>
```

In this action the final step is to redirect:

```
export const actions: Actions = {
    logout: async (event) => {
        // ...
        throw redirect(307, '/login');
    }
}
```

This was working as I intended. After updating to SvelteKit 1.0.0 the behavior changed: The action is called (as before) but when redirecting I get the following error:

> Error: No action with name 'default' found

Any ideas what needs to be changed or how this should be done?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Status code `307` will not change the method and body](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections#temporary_redirections) of the request, so the browser will try to `POST /login`.

You could change the status code to `303` instead to change the method to `GET`:

```js
export const actions: Actions = {
    logout: async (event) => {
        // ...
        throw redirect(303, '/login');
    }
}
```